# How to change more extensions in .htaccess with mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Now I have this and rewrite **index.php** to **index**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.])$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But I want also that the file names about.html change to about without the .html 
How do i do that?

Comment: Not possible. You wouldn't know if it was `.php` or `.html`

Comment: exemple.com/index.php change to exemple.com/index
But how do i change also
exemple.com/about.html to exemple.com/about

Comment: Just remove the `.html`? This has nothing to do with `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See This

**FOR REMOVE .PHP**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

**FOR REMOVE .HTML**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```